# Rails 5 rspec no route matches on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm having trouble getting this test to work.  I've looked at quite a few other SO questions/answers, but they all seem to apply to older versions of Rails.

I have a controller test where I'm attempting to use my `devices#update` route, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) DevicesController device#update is handled
     Failure/Error: patch :update, params: { device: @device }

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devices", :device=>#<Device id: 3, token: "Xn/6ut68w", nickname: "rough-snowflake-470", network: nil, ip_address: nil, gateway: nil, version: nil, ips_scan: nil, ips_exclude: nil, user_id: 3, created_at: "2018-02-21 02:44:16", updated_at: "2018-02-21 02:44:16">}
```

Which goes along with the following rspec test:

require 'rails_helper'

```
RSpec.describe DevicesController, type: :controller do

  before(:each) { @user = User.create(email: 'test@test.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') }

  it 'device#update is handled' do
    sign_in(@user)
    @device = @user.devices.first
    patch :update, params: { device: @device }
    @device.reload
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

From a backend perspective, a user is created and a `device` is automatically created for them, I've confirmed this works through other tests.

`devices_controller.rb` looks like:

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_device, only: %i[edit show update]
  respond_to :html

  def update
    if @device.update(device_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Successful update'
      respond_with :edit, :device
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Address formats allowed: x.x.x.x OR x.x.x.x-x OR x.x.x.x/x'
      respond_with :edit, :device
    end
  end

  private def set_device
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  end

  private def device_params
    params.require(:device).permit(:token, :nickname, :ips_scan, :ips_exclude)
  end
end
```

At this point, I'm just trying to get the test to work, but I really want to inject data in the `params` field for the test to verify the update actually works, such as this:

```
patch :update, params: { device: @device, nickname: 'foobar' }
```

Which just allows the user add a nickname to the device.

There is a route, so from what I've gathered, I'm not calling the `patch :update` correctly in the rspec test:

```
$ rake routes
  edit_device GET    /devices/:id/edit(.:format)    devices#edit
       device GET    /devices/:id(.:format)         devices#show
              PATCH  /devices/:id(.:format)         devices#update
              PUT    /devices/:id(.:format)         devices#update
```

What am I missing here?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check your test output by running `tail -f log/test.log`, but I'd wager you've got a parameter issue here. Try something like this:

```
patch :update, params: {
    id: @device.id, device: { nickname: 'foobar' }
}
```

You've gotta bend to [StrongParameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html).

Comment: Tailing the logs helped a lot.  The `redirect` in devices_controller.rb was the issue, since it's returning a `302`, not a `200` as I originally thought.

Answer (score 0):

for me the following worked:

```
patch device_path(@device), params: { 
  device: { nickname:"foobar"}
}
```